# How To Update Featured Image Programatically in Gutenburg

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg

I thought I’d be able to update the featured image using this code…

```
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost( { featured_media: 10 } );
```

However, I get an error:

```
Uncaught (in promise) Error: The entity being edited (postType, undefined) does not have a loaded config.
```

What needs to be changed?

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried this:

```
wp.data.select( 'core/editor' ).getEditedPostAttribute( 'featured_media' );
wp.data.dispatch( 'core/editor' ).editPost({ featured_media: 10 });
```

Comment: Have you declared register meta value in your functions.php??

Comment: No, I'm not sure what that is.

Comment: Please check my edited answer and let me know if it's working

Comment: I got the same error. Do I need todo something in my functions.php?

Comment: Could you provide a source for this? Documentation on these hooks in the Gutenberg context is sparse/incomplete. How did you know which slug to use to get and set "featured_media?" How did you know to use a media image ID instead of a URL or other way to reference an image?

Answer (score 1):

I had the same error show up in my browser console, when I was trying to make a custom post type editable through a custom-made block. In my case, it wasn't a problem with the gutenberg block itself (i.e. the js file or the registration of the block), since I could use the block in other post types without the error showing up in the console.

I would suggest checking the slugs/names of any taxonomies (and perhaps post meta fields) which are registered for your specific post type. I think I must have confused the Wordpress REST API as it was loading the post in the gutenberg editor because I had registered a reserved word as one of my taxonomies (I had a taxonomy with machine name "type"). I changed the taxonomy to "taxon_type" (hoping to avoid any name clashes), and the error went away!

I initially thought that it was a problem with a Wordpress API call that I was making in the block itself, but I believe the error message is signaling that the gutenberg editor is having trouble loading your post type for whatever reason.

Comment: This was also my issue, and you've solved it for me. We also had a taxonomy called 'type'. Thanks!